# Blackberry Enterprise Server 5.0 and SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, bes

About to install BES 5.0 and have a SQL 2008 install that I can point it to.  It looks like RIM doesn't officially support SQL 2008, only 2005, so am wondering if any server fault peeps have it running and if there are any hiccups.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question.

BES 5.0 against a remote SQL 2008 instance works like a champ.  I didn't try a local instance.

Full config is; BES 5.0 installed to Server 2008 x64.  SQL Server 2008 x64 on Server 2008 x64.  (all Hyper-V slices as well)

Have about 40 low use users and about 4 high use users.

If I run into anything down the road, I'll edit the answer.

**EDIT**

Absolutely no hiccups at all as of March 23, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to install it on a production server?  I don't have SQL2 2008 to test it, but if RIM doesn't support it I wouldn't install it on a production server.

It might not be the best option, but I think BES 5.0 comes with the ability to install to MSDE if you don't have SQL 2005 running somewhere.

EDIT:  Several users on RIM's support boards are reporting that BES 5.0 doesn't even recognize SQL is installed if you are running SQL 2008.

Comment: It's a new install that will eventually be moved to production.  I'm not going to be super concerned if major problems should up right away as I can then reinstall to MSDE.  I would like to find out if there are any gotcha's 2 months down the road.

Comment: The gotcha's 2 months down the road would be the lack of support from RIM.  Even if you get it to work, they won't support ANYTHING if you're running SQL 2008.  Since they had BES 5.0 in testing for over a year, I seriously doubt they're going to add SQL 2008 to their supported platforms matrix anytime soon.

Comment: BES 5.0 comes with SQL2005 Express rather then the MSDE finally

Answer (score 0):

TSupport says BES 5 (MR1 only v5.0.1) is supported on SQL 2008 x64 or Express with SP1.

They are having issues with SQL 2008 on Windows SBS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've got BES 4 installed against a remote SQL 2008 instance and it's working fine.  I can't imagine that BES 5 wouldn't work.  On a local instance it might be different as the server will look for services which may be named differently.

You may need to tell it that it's a remote database instance, but give it the local connection information.

Comment: How did you get that working?  I tried it and it wouldn't detect the DB engine correctly so it didn't even let me go though the installer.

Comment: I didn't do anything special at all.  Just created an account on a SQL instance on a different machine and pointed the BES installer do it.  I was using BES 4, the 5 installed may look for SQL 2008 and block the install.